# Error IndexOutOfRange / Sendkey to background application

Tags: c#

I'm trying to send a single keystroke to a program running in the background. I'm actually able to do that but for some reason I'm not able to do it with the program I want. The code works just fine in one program but when I change the process name I'm getting an error `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` and I have no clue why.

Here is my working code for one program.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AntiAfk
{
    static class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("aion.bin");
            Process game1 = processes[0];

            IntPtr p = game1.MainWindowHandle;

            SetForegroundWindow(p);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{e}");
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            SendKeys.SendWait("{e}");

        }
    }
}
```

Now if I change the "aion.bin" to "archeage.exe" it doesn't work, it throws that error. Details are as follows; Index was outside the bounds of the array. HResult -2146233080. Any ideas?

EDIT - Answer - I had the wrong process name.

Comment: are you sure that `processes` is has that item in it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate a bit?

Comment: I figured it out. I had the wrong name in there. I used Spy++ and found the process name is just "ArcheAge" not "ArcheAge.exe"